# Find a subset of lexicographically ordered strings with unicode characters starting with the same pattern

Tags: java, search, unicode-string

I need to find a subset of names in a very much internationalized project (all latin characters possible), based on a starting pattern.
For example:

```
"more, moreover", "morse"
```

with the pattern `more` will return the first two elements.
Up till now, I used a `TreeSet` with basic string ordering (i.e. with `String`-s `compareTo`) and I do the pattern matching with this code:

```
        String end = start.substring(0, start.length()-1) + (char)(start.charAt(start.length()-1) + 1);
        SortedMap<String, Long> matching= empIndexByName.subMap(start, end);
```

In words: I replace the last letter with the next one by int value, and query the subMap with `more`, `morf`.
Which of course fails in case of non ascii characters. For example if the search expression ends with `é`, `é+1` is not `f`. The two problems are that I need to compare the strings with diffent alphabets in different regions, and also somehow determine the next character in the alphabet.
Is there any way to do this with basic java (javase5), other than writing code tables of my own? (Or any good intl. libraries? I already heard about ICU.)

Comment: From your description I did not get why you couldn't just use String compares (i.e. `x.startsWith(y)`) and/or regular expressions?

Comment: You're right, I could do that, but that way I always have to search through the values sequentially, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best data structure to use for this task is a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree). Once initialized, this tree will let you quickly find all words starting in a given sequence of characters. It is relatively easy piece of coding, too.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it well enough, but this algorithm builds a tree for each string, right? This way I have to search through the names one-by-one? Or I could concatenate them, but that brings up other questions.

Comment: @david Oops, I did not realize that the link did not include Ukkonen's algorithm. Here's a [better link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_suffix_tree).

Comment: It included, I just didn't followed it :) Thanks again.